# Adding event(s) to FullCalendar causing event row container to draw across cell grid

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, fullcalendar

I am a beginner-level Meteor developer working on a project which includes a FullCalendar calendar.

I have attached a screenshot of how events are rendered on the calendar. As you can see, the crude red circles highlight my issue. As far as I understand, this issue occurs due to the table rows drawing over the cell grid. How can I fix this issue?

Here is the code from my `onRendered()` function:

```
Template.calendar.onRendered(() => {
  $('#events-calendar').fullCalendar({
    // NOTE: Put your options and callbacks here.

    events(start, end, timezone, callback) {
      let data = Events.find().fetch().map((event) => {
        event.editable = !isPast(event.start);
        return event;
      });

      if (data) {
        callback(data);
      }
    }
  });

  // NOTE: Assures the calendar updates when the DB updates (refecthEvents).
  Tracker.autorun(() => {
    Events.find().fetch();
    $('#events-calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
  });
});
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.
[image: My Calendar]

Comment: Can you show your eventRender() function from onRendered function?  There are options in event render wher you might have manipulated the html code and css( in event render function which is inside onRendered function).

Comment: I added the code in my onRender() function.

Answer (score 1):

I would say its all about playing with css like a given below example.

```
  eventRender( event, element ) {
     element.find( '.fc-content' ).html(
    `<h4>${ event.title }</h4>
     <p class="guest-count">${ event.guests } Guests</p>
     <p class="type-${ event.type }">#${ event.type }</p>
    `
  );
```

you might want to see this tutorial [meteorchef](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/reactive-calendars-with-fullcalendar/) tutorial for further reference.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! The Meteor Chef tutorial is the exact one that I followed....and I still get this issue, somehow.

Even just adding an event regularly with `events: []` gives me this issue.

Comment: what css is associated with that particular white space?  try replaying those space.

Comment: As far as I understand it is CSS code rendered by FullCalendar itself... I have tried playing around with it, but to no avail.

Comment: if you want, you can share ur github code, I can have a look :)

Comment: I am working on a project for a university course, and we are not allowed to have public repositories, unfortunately. As a result, my repository is up on BitBucket, but it's private. However, here is a link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hLuLw74r/